# Setting print area for a whole page

Tags: vba, if-statement, printing

So this is my problem:
I have a template sheet into which data is pasted. The amount of rows of data will always differ (I dont think it will ever be higher than 30, but I coded capacity of 103)
After the data is pasted, the sub should set the print area and borders accordingly, but not to the last row of data, but to the last page that contains data. I wrote this ugliness and it seems to work. I do wonder if there is a way to do this without nesting IF statements (I will have to do this all over again for a much larger data set)

```
parow = wsp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If parow <= 15 Then
        parow = 15
    Else:
        If parow <= 29 Then
            parow = 29
        Else
        If parow <= 43 Then
            parow = 43
        Else
            If parow <= 58 Then
                parow = 58
            Else
                If parow <= 73 Then
                    parow = 73
                Else
                    If parow <= 88 Then
                        parow = 88
                    Else
                        If parow <= 103 Then
                            parow = 103
                        Else
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        End If
    End If

With wsp.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$A$1:$G" & parow
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the big mess of ifs, try this:

```
Dim parow As Long
Dim dif As Long
parow = wsp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
dif = 14 - (parow mod 14)
parow = parow + dif + 1
```

From your question it looks like you want to round parow up to the nearest multiple of 14, then print that many rows + 1.

With that in mind this code first gets parow as you do originally, then works out what would need to be added to round it up to the next multiple of 14. Finally it adds that value + 1 to parow. For a shorter (but less readable option) simply use

```
parow = wsp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
parow = parow + (14 - (parow mod 14)) + 1
```

Comment: Ok, I've used this before I added the print titles, but whenever parow is equal to a multiple of 14 it adds an extra empty page, instead of keeping it as is. I guess I can add one if loop to check for this.

Comment: Figured it out! `parow = wsp.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row  If Not (parow-1) Mod 14 = 0 then parow = parow+ (parow mod 14) Else End If`